# How to prevent pyspark from adding double quotes to table name

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe which am trying to store into database like below

```
oversampled_df.write \
    .format('jdbc') \
    .option('truncate', 'true') \
    .options(url=EXT_DB_URL,
             driver='oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver',
             dbtable=DEST_DB_TBL_NAME) \
    .mode('overwrite') \
    .save()
```

yet it keeps adding double quotes `"` to column names, how can I remove this to be able to query from the tables without including them i.e.
instead of

```
select "description" from schema.table;
```

to be

```
select description from schema.table;
```

Comment: can you show your problem ? where are located the `"`?

Comment: please check updated question

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. You execute a `write`, but you show a SQL statement. What is the connection between the two ?

Comment: @Steven it keeps adding double quotes " to column names

Comment: @Exorcismus did you find a working solution to this problem?

Comment: @Arn, IIRC, use capital table names or pre-define them in sql then use them in spark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem too, my workaround is

1. create the table manually in oracle

```
CREATE TABLE schema_name.table_name(
  table_catalog                VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
  table_schema                 VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
)
```

2. add option("truncate", "true")

```
oversampled_df.write.format('jdbc').options(
      url='jdbc:oracle:thin:schema/user@ip:port/dbname',
      driver='oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver',
      dbtable='schema_name.table_name',
      user='user',
      password='password').option("truncate", "true")\
.mode('overwrite').save()
```

worked for me, hoped it helps

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it, it looks like Oracle is treating your column names as quoted identifiers where to query against it, you need it to use the double quotes and it is also case sensitive. A workaround I found was making sure that all the columns in your DataFrame are capitalised (they can have digits and underscores as well) before saving to Oracle so it treats them as nonquoted identifiers. Them, you should be able to query them in either lower or upper case e.g. DESCRIPTION or description, without the need for double quotes.